# Embed?object not working in https in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, https, embed

Im embeding svg file in server side as below

```
out.println("<html><body>");
out.println("<embed src=\"" + imagePath  + "\" type=\"image/svg+xml\"/>");
out.println("</html></body>");
```

the embeded SVG is rendered in chrome,IE when HTTP is used, but the same is not working in IE (8) when HTTPS is used.

Content type is set as below

```
 response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
```

Comment: "Not working"; do you mean it is not displaying, not loading, not displaying correctly?

Comment: Did you mean in IE 8? If so, note that it lacks native support for svg.

Comment: @  rfornal : It is not displaying, im getting just a white screen.
@ Erik Dahlström : I have svg viewer installed in my machine.